# is there any tools that help me to find all the messages from my computer out,not just the HTTP message via the browser?

Tags: http, postman

postman is perfect!with it i can know most of the HTTP messages.but now i wonder if there is any tools like that one to help me know all the messages between my computer and outer world,not just the HTTP messages

Comment: I'd say you are looking for a network sniffer. `wireshark` is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use fiddler, it's a web debugging proxy that I'm using most of the time on HTTP protocole but not only as you can capture FTP protocole for example.

You can also re-edit your request and have lots of interaction as web debugging  :

> http://www.telerik.com/fiddler